# error "stream not support reading"

Tags: c#

Me devuelve este error:

```
stream not support reading
```

código:

```
internal static byte[] Compress(byte[] data)
        {
            MemoryStream memout = new MemoryStream();
            using (MemoryStream memin = new MemoryStream(data))
            {
                using (CryptoStream crypto = new CryptoStream(memin, new DESCryptoServiceProvider().CreateEncryptor(new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes("87654321"), new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes("12345678")), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (DeflateStream stream = new DeflateStream(crypto, CompressionMode.Compress))
                    {
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                        int numRead;
                        while ((numRead = stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
                        {
                            memout.Write(buffer, 0, numRead);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return memout.ToArray();
        }
```

Retorna el mismo error:

```
internal static byte[] Compress(byte[] data)
        {
            MemoryStream memout = new MemoryStream();
            using (MemoryStream memin = new MemoryStream(data))
            {
                using (CryptoStream crypto = new CryptoStream(memin, new DESCryptoServiceProvider().CreateEncryptor(new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes("87654321"), new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes("12345678")), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (DeflateStream stream = new DeflateStream(crypto, CompressionMode.Compress)) { 
                        stream.CopyTo(memout);
                        memout.Position = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            return memout.ToArray();
        }
```

y no sé porque da este error.

Comment: Acabo de probar el codigo actualizado y no me lanza el error. En que linea es que te lo muestra?

Comment: si lo probe y compilo pero aora me devuelve un error stream not support reading no entiendo porque puse el codigo correcto de nuevo.

Comment: En vez de simplemente dejar un comentario breve, por favor edita tu pregunta para que quede claro cual es tu problema ahora. La pregunta en su estado actual no se puede contestar.

Comment: edite la pregunta con el error.

Comment: edite el titulo tambien.

Answer (score 1):

Estás encadenando los streams incorrectamente. Estás usando el `CryptoStream` y el `DeflateStream` en modo lectura, cuando debería ser al revés. Nota tu uso de `CryptoStreamMode.Write`.

Mas bien, usa el `CryptoStream` en modo escritura, pasándole `memout` en vez de `memin`.

Ejemplo de código:

```
internal static byte[] Compress(byte[] data)
{
    MemoryStream memout = new MemoryStream();
    using (CryptoStream crypto = new CryptoStream(memout, new DESCryptoServiceProvider().CreateEncryptor(new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes("87654321"), new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes("12345678")), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
    using (DeflateStream deflate = new DeflateStream(crypto, CompressionMode.Compress))
    using (MemoryStream memin = new MemoryStream(data))
    {
        memin.CopyTo(deflate);
    }

    return memout.ToArray();
}
```

Toma en cuenta que con el código arriba, el orden de operaciones es que primero comprime, y luego encripta. No estoy claro si esa es tu intención.

Si más bien deseabas encriptar primero, y luego comprimir, tendrías que invertir algunas líneas de esta manera:

```
internal static byte[] Compress(byte[] data)
{
    MemoryStream memout = new MemoryStream();
    using (DeflateStream deflate = new DeflateStream(memout, CompressionMode.Compress))
    using (CryptoStream crypto = new CryptoStream(deflate, new DESCryptoServiceProvider().CreateEncryptor(new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes("87654321"), new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes("12345678")), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
    using (MemoryStream memin = new MemoryStream(data))
    {
        memin.CopyTo(crypto);
    }

    return memout.ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El método Write no retorna ningún valor :

```
//invalido Write no retorna 
    while ((numRead = stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
```

Intenta utilizando el método `CopyTo(Stream)` para copiar el contenido del Stream en la variable `memout`:

```
    using (DeflateStream stream = new DeflateStream(crypto, CompressionMode.Compress)) { 
    stream.CopyTo(memout);
memout.Position = 0;
    }
```

Comment: pero entonces tendría que quitar todo el codigo restante? lo que intentaba era encriptar los datos y retornarlo como un array.

Comment: Solo reemplazarias el código del using del DeflateStream. Es incómodo agregar y editar todo el código desde el móvil.

Comment: lo puse y devuelve el mismo te pongo en el post de arriba lo que puse.

Comment: A que te refieres con que devuelve el mismo?

Comment: cannot implicity convert tipo void to int.